# How to fix "Error running JSHint Package" in Atom Editor

Tags: javascript, windows, atom-editor, jshint, linter

Every time I edit a JS file in Atom, I get this error:

[image: [Linter] Error running JSHint]

Which looks like this in the console:

```
e[0716/144445.466: ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] <embedded>:14
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (x2)

[0716/144447.414: ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] <embedded>:14
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

[0716/145116.108: ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] <embedded>:14
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (x2)

[0716/145122.599: ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] <embedded>:14
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (@x2)

[Linter] Error running JSHint C:\Users\mjwhi\.atom..ter\dist\index.js:1
Error: [0716/145122.942:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)]
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (x2)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mjwhi\.atom\packages\linter-
jshint\node_modules\sb-exec\lib\index.js:56:20)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
at maybeClose (internal/child process.js:1021:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child process.js:28
3:5)

[0716/145125.805:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] <embedded>:14
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (@x2)

[0716/145126.827: ERROR:registration protocol_win.cc(103)] <embedded>:14
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (x2)

[0716/145128.028: ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] <embedded>:14
CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (x2)
```

or here it is formatted better:

[image: formatted error as seen above]

This appears regardless of my project folder so it doesn't seem to be a project-specific configuration issue. Uninstalling and reinstalling JSHint doesn't seem to help, nor does restarting Atom. And disabling the package stops the errors from popping up, but obviously isn't a real solution. How do I fix this?

Comment: Disabling the package makes the errors go away, but the root problem isn't fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the deprecated `jshint` package (https://atom.io/packages/jshint), then install `linter-jshint`, then uninstall the deprecated `jshint` package. After that, restart Atom.
You can find a better explanation here: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jshint/issues/377

Comment: Seemed to work. In that Github forum, he said the errors came back and he never did find a permanent solution. The best solution might just be to switch to ESLint instead, as it is better maintained.